# Calculating summary statistic across subsets of dataset [What is the equivalent of Stata's "bysort" in R?]

Tags: r, stata

I have been programming in Stata the last few years and have recently switched to R about 4 months ago.

I have data in the following format:

```
       popname sex year age COUNTRY
329447     AUS   f 1921  23     AUS
329448     AUS   f 1921  24     AUS
329449     AUS   f 1921  25     AUS
329450     AUS   f 1921  26     AUS
329451     AUS   f 1921  27     AUS
329452     AUS   f 1921  28     AUS
...
329532     AUS   f 1922  23     AUS
329533     AUS   f 1922  24     AUS
329534     AUS   f 1922  25     AUS
...        ...   .  ..   ..     ...
297729     BLR   f 1987  59     BLR
297730     BLR   f 1987  60     BLR
297731     BLR   f 1987  61     BLR
... 
291941     BLR   m 1973  71     BLR
291942     BLR   m 1973  72     BLR
291993     BLR   m 1974  23     BLR
```

I would like to create a new summary variable called Max.Age (which calculates the maximum Age for a given subgroup defined by {popname, sex,year) in the existing dataset as follows:

```
   popname sex year age COUNTRY   max.age
329447     AUS   f 1921  23     AUS   72  
329448     AUS   f 1921  24     AUS   72
329449     AUS   f 1921  25     AUS   72
329450     AUS   f 1921  26     AUS   72
329451     AUS   f 1921  27     AUS   72
329452     AUS   f 1921  28     AUS   72
...
329532     AUS   f 1922  23     AUS   75
329533     AUS   f 1922  24     AUS   75
329534     AUS   f 1922  25     AUS   75
...        ...   .  ..   ..     ...
297729     BLR   f 1987  59     BLR   87
297730     BLR   f 1987  60     BLR   87
297731     BLR   f 1987  61     BLR   87
... 
291941     BLR   m 1973  71     BLR   78
291942     BLR   m 1973  72     BLR   78
291993     BLR   m 1974  23     BLR   78
```

To do this in Stata, one would use the *egen* command with the *by* command as follows:

```
by State City Day, sort:
egen cnt=seq(), from(23) to(72) block(1);
```

I tried doing this in R, using the doBy package. Here's the code I wrote:

```
IDB <- orderBy(~popname+sex+year+age, data=IDB)
v<-lapplyBy(~sex+year, data=IDB, function(d) c(NA,max(d$age)))
IDB$Max.age <- unlist(v)
```

This doesn't work, as *lapplyBy* returns an aggregated dataset of smaller length than the original dataset (IDB).

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction on how to essentially implement a "by | egen" type Stata code in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

One thing you'll find with R is that there isn't just one way to do things.  One way is via the `ave` function.

```
IDB$max.age <- ave(IDB$age, IDB$popname, IDB$sex, IDB$year, FUN=max)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `ddply` from the `plyr` package (although there are many ways to do something like this). Assuming your dataframe is called `dat`:

```
result <- ddply(dat,.(popname,sex,year),.fun = function(x){
                                         x$max.age <- max(x$age,na.rm=TRUE)
                                         return(x)})
```

The anonymous function in the ddply adds a column to each piece with the max age for that piece.

Comment: +1 for suggesting ddply. That's what I'd suggest, but you did first.

Answer (score 3):

I found the Stata egen documentation to be completely opaque when I tried reading it a couple of years ago, so I will not be giving you a general answer. The function to use for this purpose (returning a vector of same length from a function applied with groups is `ave()`:

```
dfrm$max.age <- with( dfrm, ave(age, list(popname, sex,year), FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE) )
```

You do get warnings but the operation succeeds. Perhaps the cross-product of the grouping variables creates empty categories that are later discarded. They also occur with Joshua's version, and removing the na.rm=TRUE does not change the warnings:

```
1: In FUN(X[[20L]], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: I believe the warnings are because `ave` uses `interaction` and some of the interactions between the groups have no observations.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do now using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
IDB %>% group_by(popname, sex, year) %>% mutate(max.age = max(age))
```